# Processing all frames in an AVAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to go through each frame in an `AVAsset` and process each frame as if it were an image. I have not been able to find anything from my searches.

The task I am trying to accomplish  would look like this in pseudo-code

```
for each frame in asset

      take the frame as an image and convert to a cvMat
      Process and store data of center points
      Store center points in array
```

The only part in that pseudo-code I do not know how to write is the going though each frame and capturing it in an image.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

One answer is to use [AVAssetImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/index.html).

1) Load the movie file into an `AVAsset` object.
2) Create an `AVAssetImageGenerator` object.
3) Pass in an estimated time of the frame where you want to get an image back from the movie.

Setting the 2 properties `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` and `requestedTimeToleranceAfter` on the `AVAssetImageGenerator` object to `kCMTimeZero` will increase the ability to get individual frames, but increases the processing time.

However this method is slow and I have not found a faster way.

```
//Load the Movie from a URL
self.movieAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.movieURL];
NSArray *movieTracks = [self.movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack *movieTrack = [movieTracks objectAtIndex:0];

//Make the image Generator    
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:self.movieAsset];

//Create a variables for the time estimation
Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.movieAsset.duration);
Float64 timePerFrame = 1.0 / (Float64)movieTrack.nominalFrameRate;
Float64 totalFrames = durationSeconds * movieTrack.nominalFrameRate;

//Step through the frames
for (int counter = 0; counter <= totalFrames; counter++){
    CMTime actualTime;
    Float64 secondsIn = ((float)counter/totalFrames)*durationSeconds;
    CMTime imageTimeEstimate = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(secondsIn, 600);
    NSError *error;
    CGImageRef image = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:imageTimeEstimate actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    ...Do some processing on the image

    CGImageRelease(image);    
}
```

Comment: I get result always aligned to 0s 1s 2s 3s
can't get intermediate frame

Answer (score 2):

You could simply gen each frame using AVAssetReaderTrackOutput:

```
            let asset = AVAsset(url: inputUrl)
            let reader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
            let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
            let outputSettings = [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
            let trackReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack,
                                                             outputSettings: outputSettings)

            reader.add(trackReaderOutput)
            reader.startReading()

            while let sampleBuffer = trackReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
                    // do what you want
                }
            }
```