# Cannot view each frame of a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to read a video frame by frame and I used the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600979/processing-all-frames-in-an-avasset) to do the same. My issue is that I'm not able to view the image created.

I tried writing it to a PNG file (commented code) and that seems to be working. Is there a reason why the UIImageView is not displaying the UIImage? I tried running it on the main thread using dispatch_async. That didn't solve the problem either. I'm on iOS 10.3.3

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"recording2" withExtension:@"mov"];
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

    NSArray *movieTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVAssetTrack *movieTrack = [movieTracks objectAtIndex:0];

    AVAssetImageGenerator* generator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    //Create a variables for the time estimation
    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
    Float64 timePerFrame = 1.0 / (Float64)movieTrack.nominalFrameRate;
    Float64 totalFrames = durationSeconds * movieTrack.nominalFrameRate;

    //Step through the frames
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= totalFrames; counter++){

//        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//        
//        NSString *folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png", counter];
//        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
//        
//        // Save image.
//        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        CMTime actualTime;
        Float64 secondsIn = ((float)counter/totalFrames)*durationSeconds;
        CMTime imageTimeEstimate = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(secondsIn, 600);
        NSError *error;
        CGImageRef image = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:imageTimeEstimate actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description); // Always (null)
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];

        CGImageRelease(image);
```

Thanks.

Comment: did u try adding images to an array, and pass the array to the image view ?

Comment: I can try that approach. But I want to process the frames as soon as they arrive. It's not just about playing the video. I need to process each frame as well.

Comment: Why not to use `AVAssetReader`, or if you want to play a video use `AVVideoCompositing`